# Legend in graph with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, legend

I need to make a legend for my graph in TikZ, but I need that legend would be from 3 columns, how can I do this?

I use this code:

```
\newenvironment{customlegend}[1][]{%
    \begingroup

    \csname pgfplots@init@cleared@structures\endcsname
    \pgfplotsset{#1}%
}{
    \csname pgfplots@createlegend\endcsname
    \endgroup
}%

\def\addlegendimage{\csname pgfplots@addlegendimage\endcsname}
\pgfkeys{/pgfplots/number in legend/.style={%
        /pgfplots/legend image code/.code={%
            \node at (0.125,-0.0225){#1}; % <= changed x value
        },%
    },
} \pgfplotsset{ every legend to name picture/.style={west} }

------
\begin{customlegend}[legend cell align=left, %<= to align cells
legend entries={ % <= in the following there are the entries
ac, csv },
legend style={at={(-1,-9)},font=\tiny}] % <= to define position and font legend
% the following are the "images" and numbers in the legend
    \addlegendimage{->,dash
pattern=on 4pt off 2pt on 4pt off 2pt on 4pt off 2pt on 1pt off
2pt,black!40!red,very thick}
    \addlegendimage{->,dash pattern=on 4pt off 2pt on 4pt off 2pt on 4pt off
2pt on 1pt off 2pt,olive!30!purple,very thick}

\end{customlegend}
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by the legend "coming from 3 columns"?

Comment: If you mean that you want to have the legend entries in three columns, add `legend style={legend columns=3}` to the `axis` options. See the example on page 175-176 of [the manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplots). (end of section 4.8.5)